# Appium with WD and Mocha testing - Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated (status: 12)

Tags: automated-tests, integration-testing, appium

## The Problem:

#### Android Emulator

Tests work perfectly.

#### iOS Emulator

The test in question is verifying form validations on an ionic hybrid application. After initial form interaction on the emulator the following tests all fail as they are unable to utilize clear() or sendKeys() commands; the below error is thrown.

`Error: [element.sendKeys("firstName")] Error response status: 13, UnknownError - An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Selenium error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error while executing atom: Element is not currently inter-actable and may not be manipulated (status: 12)`

Adding delay times between tests has no effect, changing the order of the tests results in the first one passing and the rest failing. Putting the tests in different test files results in them all passing. Any suggestions much appreciated!!

#### Manually

Interfacing with the app manually in the emulator the form inputs are all active after responding to an input validation and I am able to submit the form a second time.

#### Environment

- Appium version: 1.72
- Desktop OS/version : MAC OS High Sierra 10.13.3
- Node.js version: 6.10.3
- platform/version under test: iOS 10.3

#### My Code

[Test Code](https://gist.github.com/markring/dc22abddf7d3724bad8a6a90231b86e2)

[Appium Logs](https://gist.github.com/markring/1e04ecc1ffa9506f96596f09518d678d)

Comment: This error _does_ indicate a timing issue. Could you show us some code and where exactly you set your sleeps/delays? Does the app at any point in time redirect or refresh the interface after you searched for an element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get it working through the use of the retries method provided by the Mocha framework, not sure this is the most effective solution though.

https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/10256

describe('XYZ SCREEN: xyz.test.js',  function() {

```
this.retries(30);

it('Should do something',  async function() {
   await test code ...
});
```

});